# Discrepancy of a divisor over a different model

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

I also asked this question on MathStackExchange but receive no answers.

I'm reading Koll'ar and Mori's book about singularity theory. They state the following lemma without proof:

> Lemma 2.30. Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a proper birational morphism between normal varieties. Let $\Delta_Y$ resp. $\Delta_X$ be $\mathbb Q$-divisors on $Y$ resp. $X$ such that
> $$K_Y + \Delta_Y\equiv f^*(K_X+\Delta_X)\quad \text{and}\quad f_*\Delta_Y = \Delta_X$$
> Then for any divisor $F$ over $X$, we have $a(F,Y,\Delta_Y) = a(F,X,\Delta_X)$.

My questions are:

1. $F$ is a divisor over $X$ but it may not be a divisor over $Y$. Because when we define $F$, we need a model $g:Z\rightarrow X$ such that $F$ is a divisor on $Z$, but we don't know if $g$ factors through $f$. If $F$ is not over $Y$, how do we define $a(Y,\Delta_Y,F)?$
2. I know how to prove it when $F$ is also over $Y$. But if $F$ is not over $Y$, how do we prove it?

Comment: You can always further blow up $Z$ to get a model with $F$ on it that factors through $Y$. The point is that the discrepancy is independent of the choice of model containing $F$.

Comment: @DoriBejleri If we blow up $Z$ and pullback $F$ to the new model, does that change the discrepancy? Could we say discrepancy is a birational invariant?

Comment: You need to take the strict transform of $F$ on the new model as $F$ should be a prime divisor. Since any two models containing $F$ are isomorphic at the generic point of $F$, the discrepency is the same.